# Retrieve Subscriber from Suppression List

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, suppressionlist

Im trying to retrieve the subscriber from suppression list. But, each time rowcount appears to be 0. Could anyone take a look and let me know where i went wrong?

```
    %%[

SET @rr = CreateObject("RetrieveRequest")
SetObjectProperty(@rr, "ObjectType", "ListSubscriber")
AddObjectArrayItem(@rr, "Properties", "ListID")
AddObjectArrayItem(@rr, "Properties", "SubscriberKey")

SET @sfp1 = CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart")
   SetObjectProperty(@sfp1, "Property", "ListID")
   SetObjectProperty(@sfp1, "SimpleOperator", "Equals")
   AddObjectArrayItem(@sfp1, "Value","3909")
   SetObjectProperty(@rr,"Filter",@sfp1)
SET @sfp2 = CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart")
SetObjectProperty(@sfp2,"Property","SubscriberKey")
SetObjectProperty(@sfp2,"SimpleOperator","Equals")
AddObjectArrayItem(@sfp2,"Value","1002")

Set @cf1 = CreateObject("ComplexFilterPart")
SetObjectProperty(@cf1,"LeftOperand",@sfp1)
SetObjectProperty(@cf1,"RightOperand",@sfp2)   
SetObjectProperty(@cf1,"LogicalOperator","AND")

SetObjectProperty(@rr,"Filter",@sfp1)


SET @rows = InvokeRetrieve(@rr, @null, null)

]%%
%%=rowcount(@rows)=%%
```

Answer (score 1):

```
%%[

SET @rr = CreateObject("RetrieveRequest")
SetObjectProperty(@rr, "ObjectType", "ListSubscriber")
AddObjectArrayItem(@rr, "Properties", "ListID")
AddObjectArrayItem(@rr, "Properties", "SubscriberKey")

SET @sfp1 = CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart")
   SetObjectProperty(@sfp1, "Property", "ListID")
   SetObjectProperty(@sfp1, "SimpleOperator", "Equals")
   AddObjectArrayItem(@sfp1, "Value","3909")
   SetObjectProperty(@rr,"Filter",@sfp1)
SET @sfp2 = CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart")
SetObjectProperty(@sfp2,"Property","SubscriberKey")
SetObjectProperty(@sfp2,"SimpleOperator","Equals")
AddObjectArrayItem(@sfp2,"Value","1002")

Set @cf1 = CreateObject("ComplexFilterPart")
SetObjectProperty(@cf1,"LeftOperand",@sfp1)
SetObjectProperty(@cf1,"RightOperand",@sfp2)   
SetObjectProperty(@cf1,"LogicalOperator","AND")

SetObjectProperty(@rr,"Filter",@cf1)


SET @rows = InvokeRetrieve(@rr)

]%%
%%=rowcount(@rows)=%%
```

You do not have to add null null to your call on InvokeRetrieve and especially not `@null, null`.

Instead

```
SET @rows = InvokeRetrieve(@rr, @null, null)
```

This:

```
SET @rows = InvokeRetrieve(@rr)
```

Furthermore you have only applied one filter to your call (instead of @spf1 you need to set @cf1).

Instead

```
SetObjectProperty(@rr,"Filter",@sfp1)
```

Use this

```
SetObjectProperty(@rr,"Filter",@cf1)
```

And please check if the values are correct for your lists (3909) and (1002). If those do not exist you will get a rowcount of "0".

Comment: Hi @Johannes, i have updated the code as per your answer and still the rowcount shows 0. I was checking the SupressionList Data object and got to know that, we can only Create, Update or Delete from the Suppression List.

Comment: The code I have posted is definitely working. I tested it inside a cloudpage gainst the listsubscriber dataview and inserted a valid customer and the ID for the allSubscriber List. Definitely showed correct values. When I did not filter on a particular subscriber I got 2500 which is the maximum to get from one single call and 1 if I filtered it down to the subscriber. Please double check the values you entered as filter.

Comment: HI @johannes did you use all subscriber list to retrieve or suppression list?

Comment: I used the ID of the subscriberlist (which is 358 for me) and used a test subscriber which is on this list to evaluate that it returns 1. It did. When you do the same for any different list with a valid ID it should also return the correct value. Whatever list it is it should not be any different.

Comment: unfortunately, i have tried with both publication and suppression list. it isnt retrieving the record. But, when i use the same code to retrieve it from the normal list. I get the rowcount as 1.

Comment: According to this [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_query_find_subscribers_on_a_publication_or_suppression_list_ref.htm&type=5) both of these lists are inside the Listsubscribers dataview. Other people like Adam Spriggs did it the same way like [here](https://sprignaturemoves.com/check-list-membership-on-a-landing-page/)